# Interchange the display of Divs using PHP for multiple URLs using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, json

we have thousands of articles on our website and we are displaying B-Schools Ads on all article pages. Now we have to show different AD on TOP 30 articles, so assuming that those TOP 30 articles will keep on changing among TOP 50 articles. We will put the div of Both ADs on TOP 50 Articles.

Is it possible to use IF...ELSE using PHP to interchange (Display) DIVs (of ADs) for TOP 30 URLs of the Articles.?

Comment: Yes it should be possible to use an for each then if else if you include some code we can try and find a solution.

Comment: Yes, I have tried a bit and come up with the code and it is quite helpful

Comment: then I am glad I was in some form of assistance to you.

Comment: Thanks, Everone for Showing Interest. I have resolved the issue  .